# Error 530 upon FTP Request with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ftp

I'm trying to get a response from my FTP server via a PowerShell Script. To do this I have written the following:

```
$sourceuri = "<string>"
$targetpath = "<string>"
$username = "<string>"
$password = "<string>"

# Create a FTPWebRequest object to handle the connection to the ftp server
$ftprequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::create($sourceuri)

# set the request's network credentials for an authenticated connection
$ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password, $sourceuri)

$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
$ftprequest.UseBinary = $true
$ftprequest.KeepAlive = $false

# send the ftp request to the server
$ftpresponse = $ftprequest.GetResponse()
```

Upon script execution it returns error 530 saying that I am not logged in. I have no PowerShell experience and am unsure of what I need to add to fix this error

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be this line

```
$ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password, $sourceuri)
```

The only [constructor that accepts 3 parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cytcd70k(v=vs.110).aspx) for `[System.Net.NetworkCredential]` is looking for username, password, *domain*. You have `$sourceuri` in place for `domain`.`$sourceuri` is the FTP url is it not? I should think that if you are just using basic FTP credentials you need to just have username and password.

```
$ftprequest.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username,$password)
```

Comment: $sourceuri is a string I believe. Taking out $sourceuri changes the error to a 550 error which I have no idea how to fix

Comment: @NickG That just means permission denied. Is `$sourceuri` a webaddress correct? Can you can use those credentials in a browser? Does it use domain credentials?

Comment: The credentials work in a browser. I just ran another script that lists the directory in my shell and that worked. However a download script throws the 550 error

Comment: I'm using Windows Server 2012, where would I go to authenticate FTP?